# Change some text in superset

Tags: apache-superset

I am trying to customize Apache Superset, where in there are certain text which i want to replace with something else. I tried changing the text directly in code but those changes are not getting reflected. Is there any other way to change the text?

P.S. I am using a Docker image of Superset.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to change? I might be able to point you in the right direction. 

Also, just to confirm, when you change the text, are you waiting for webpack to rebuild before refreshing the page?

Comment: I am trying to change some default text like where they have superset references like tutorial links on add chart etc. I am using docker image of superset. So how exactly can i build the code again after making changes. I am following this link https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/superset  . Let me know if I am missing something.